# how to run compiled project in windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gtk, clion

I started to get acquainted with c ++ and there was a problem. I can’t understand how I can compile and test. I installed the compiler in vm Linux and configured the clion on a remote host. I connected the gtk to develop the interface and when I compile I get this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6cyK.png).
How can i run it? If i am do this from clion getting this error 
Gtk-WARNING **: 12:53:54.419: cannot open display: :0, so i need run it in windows without install something. Help me pls.

[cmakelist.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF3yT.png)

Comment: Note the "pvk" file next to your "pvk.cpp". That is probably your executable. Without seeing your CMakeLists.txt we cannot tell more.

Comment: @Botje thanks for answer, added cmakelist to the question.

Comment: Does your remote machine has display set up (real or virtual)?
BTW, your title is about compiling, but in the description you are talking about running your executable. Please correct it otherwise no one will able to help you.

Comment: @MaximBanaev if I understand your question correctly, then I have installed xfce on my vm. Or do I still need to adjust the display? Anyway i need run my compiled build in windows. I think something is wrong in cmakelists.txt and my project compiled for Linux.